# Extract HyperLinks from Webpage using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

Need help to extract hyper link of each product (like Philadelphia: One Liberty Observation Deck ) from below page :

https://www.getyourguide.com/s/?q=Philadelphia

I have applied general approach like :

```
url <- "http://www.viator.com/search/Philadelphia"
doc <- htmlParse(url)
links <- xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href")
```

but I am getting error.
I am looking for output data frame like

```
product1: Philadelphia: One Liberty Observation Deck 
link1 : "https://www.getyourguide.com/philadelphia-l60/philadelphia-one-liberty-observation-deck-t61908/"

product2 : Philadelphia Hop-on Hop-off Bus Tour Tickets
link2 : "https://www.getyourguide.com/philadelphia-l60/philadelphia-hop-on-hop-off-bus-tour-t47403/"
```

Again, I am very new to all that is programming, so any help or code snippets will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting? If possible, edit it into your question so someone can help find out what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these links you are looking for are not in the code of the source page, They are loaded with javascript from JSON file 
which you can see here https://www.getyourguide.com/s/search.json?q=Philadelphia.

try this code you should get vector of links

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
url<-"https://www.getyourguide.com/s/search.json?q=Philadelphia"
url2<-getURL(url)
parsed<-htmlParse(url2)
links<-xpathSApply(parsed,path = "//a",xmlGetAttr,"href")
```